# SQL Managment Studio Express - Project and Solutions

Tags: sql-server-express, ssms

I have SQL Managment Studio Express, but notice it doesnt have the add on for solution and project creation. Is there a download to add that functionality so I can group my queries and connections? Or is this funcationality not available for express?

Answer (score 2):

No, that functionality isn't available in Express.  If you're looking for a freeware product to do that, check out Quest Toad for SQL Server, which is available in free and beta editions:

http://www.toadsoft.com/toadsqlserver/toad_sqlserver.htm